# Error in xcode when run

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have a project with Cordova and when I went to do run, this error has appeared:

[image]

I dont know how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: I think solution is available here try it out. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3983

Comment: @oihi08 Did you installed nodejs globally? Also could you share your project structure? Are you using any hook before build?